# C on Linux: Parse arguments from '<' and '|'

Tags: c, linux, command-line, parameter-passing

For an uni assignment The following program has to be implemented:

```
mysort [-r] [file1, ...]
```

mysort then takes the content of each passed file, gets the content line-by-line and prints them alphabetically sorted. -r reverses the output order.

Example file t1:

```
Priority9 cat
Priority2 ls
Priority7 cat mysort.h
```

When mysort is called:

```
$ ./mysort -r t1 t1
Priority9 cat
Priority9 cat
Priority7 cat mysort.h
Priority7 cat mysort.h
Priority2 ls
Priority2 ls
```

This works perfectly fine so far using argc/argv, but here comes the tricky part. The following calls must also work:

```
$ cat t1 | ./mysort
Priority2 ls
Priority7 cat mysort.h
Priority9 cat

$ ./mysort < t1
Priority2 ls
Priority7 cat mysort.h
Priority9 cat
```

These do not show up in argc and argv, and presumably have to be handled somehow else. Even after a good bit of googling, I am unable to find ressources on this.(I assume this technique has a particular name?)

Comment: It is not clear if this is a question about shell-uage or programming. Did you read the man-page of your shell (presumably bash)?

Answer (score 2):

`|` and `<` use `stdin`.

So if the user does not pass any filenames, then use `stdin` as your file.
Something like this perhaps.

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int did_process_file = 0;
    int reverse = 0;
    char * arg;

    // Read arguments
    for (arg = argv[1]; arg != NULL; ++arg) {
        if (strcmp(arg, "-r") == 0) {
            reverse = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            FILE * f = fopen(arg, "r");
            load_file(f);
            did_process_file = 1;
        }
    }

    if (!did_process_file)
    {
        load_file(stdin);
    }

    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `cat t1 | ./mysort` *pipes* the output of `cat t1` to the standard input stream of `./mysort`; similarly, `./mysort < t1` *redirects* the standard input stream of `./mysort` to the file `t1`.  In either case, you would read the file contents from `stdin`.

Basically, you'd handle it like so:

```
FILE *input = stdin; // initially assume input will come through stdin;
if ( argv_contains_a_file_name )
{
  input = fopen( argv[i], "r" );
}
```